# Python Confunde una Tupla con una variable NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación hecha en Python3 usando la librería de tKinter para el tema gráfico.

En una parte de la app, hago una consulta a la base de datos que me devuelve una tupla, pero al hacer un len() de la misma, se queja diciendo que es tipo NoneType

```
def updateFormConns(_idConn , _accessData , _listEntries , _lblNumVars , _frameFormConnInfo):
    #Hacemos consulta
    sql_infoConnType = <SENTENCIA>
    result_infoConnType = MySQLFunctions.execSentence(_accessData,sql_infoConnType)
```

#Aquí compruebo que devuelve una tupla

```
    print("\n\n\nTipo:" , type(result_infoConnType) , " Valor LEN " , len(result_infoConnType))
```

#Aquí es donde se queja

```
    if(len(result_infoConnType) > 0):
        #Ponemos el frame en visible
        _frameFormConnInfo.pack(pady=10)
```

El terminal muestra lo siguiente:

Aquí empieza el error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Llamo a la función desde una lambda

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/dataLogger/betas/beta_1/funciones/screens.py", line 505, in <lambda>
    optDocConnVariable.trace("w", lambda *args: [funcionesEspecificas.updateFormConns(<PARAMS>)])
```

Aquí está donde dice que result_infoConnType es de tipo NoneType

```
  File "/home/pi/Documents/dataLogger/betas/beta_1/funciones/funcionesEspecificas.py", line 194, in updateFormConns
    if(len(result_infoConnType) > 0):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Aquí sale el print con el tipo de la tupla y el valor del LEN:

```
Tipo: <class 'tuple'>  Valor LEN  1
```

La función funciona correctamente, y devuelve lo que tiene que devolver, pero me sale ese error en el terminal y es molesto, he intentado suprimirlo mediante:

```
import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

Pero sigue apareciendo.

Cualquier comentario es bienvenido.

Gracias por leer.

Comment: @Haaa... bueno, lo siento no lo había entendido, recién me había despertado y estaba en mi cel

Comment: Honestamente, no creo que python _confunda_ esto que dices.  Ya que TU probablemente lo estás confundiendo, habría que ver la secuencia de código relevante y no solo los fragmentos que has mostrado. OJO, no pido todo el código, un [mcve] es lo ideal.